# Atom-beautify not loading php-cs-fixer custom config

Tags: php, atom-editor, atom-beautify

I have Atom installed with PHP-CS-Fixer plugin. I'm trying to use some custom rules to apply same-line braces style.

I have tried using the in-Atom config option, but couldn't make it work. I have tried setting `position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs` and putting it in `PHP-CS-FIXER Rules` in Atom, but didn't work.

Therefore, I have set a custom path to my config, which is `C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\atom.php_cs`

The config is:

```
<?php

$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    //->exclude('somedir')
    //->notPath('src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.php'
    ->in(__DIR__)
;

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'strict_param' => false,
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'long'],
        'braces' => [
            'allow_single_line_closure' => true, 
            'position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs' => 'same'],
    ])
    ->setFinder($finder)
;
```

It didn't work and Atom is NOT doing a proper beautify. Any idea to enforce the rules?

Notes:

I'm interested in having the following style:

```
  public function someFunction(){ 
    // code here
}
```

- I'm using Windows 10 as OS, Atom is IDE and have PHP-cs-fixer installed via Composer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the beautification is not working properly the programm might have run into an error.
You can run *Atom Beautify: Help Debug Editor* from the command pallette to get Debug information.
Your config works perfectly fine for me and the problem seems to be your naming.

Simply rename your **atom.php_cs** to **.php_cs** and remove any config file path from the settings.

Comment: The debug doesn't show anything regarding the php beautification. The issue is that the Atom-beautify is not following my rules and simply using the default ones. Regarding the php_cs path, I have set it in the settings of Atom and used the absolute path of the file with the .php_cs ending.

Comment: @Jaeger The issue is that it cannot find your file. If I copy and paste your settings it works perfectly fine. Have you tried to delete the absolute path from the settings and rename the file to .php_cs(without anything else in the name)? It should show at least something in your debug log. Try to scroll all the way to the bottom and look there or search for the word "error" in the log

Comment: Renaming the file doesn't get applied because Windows doesn't accept empty named files.

Comment: Thank you!! The config is correct as you've said. The problem was with the additional naming to the config file. It's really a weird issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For any newcomers, please note that the new version needs the config file to be named `.php-cs-fixer.php`. It's so funny that I googled, and saw my question, lol.

Make sure that php-cs-fixer is installed globally with fixer, and restart Atom after you do all these changes to make sure that it's applied.

Also, new config would look like this

```
<?php

$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->in(__DIR__)
;

$config = new PhpCsFixer\Config();
$config->setRules([
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'strict_param' => false,
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'long'],
        'no_spaces_around_offset' => [
          'positions' => [ "inside", "outside" ]
        ],
        'no_spaces_inside_parenthesis' => true,
        'array_indentation' => true,
        'no_extra_blank_lines' => true,
        'object_operator_without_whitespace' => true,
        'multiline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => true,
        'switch_case_space' => true,
        'indentation_type' => true,
        'blank_line_after_namespace' => true,
        "no_break_comment"=> true,
        "no_closing_tag"=> true,
        'switch_case_semicolon_to_colon' => true,
        "no_spaces_after_function_name"=> true,
        "no_trailing_whitespace"=> true,
        "no_trailing_whitespace_in_comment"=> true,
        'no_whitespace_before_comma_in_array'=> true,
        'braces' => [
            'allow_single_line_closure' => true,
            'position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs' => 'same'],
    ])
    ->setFinder($finder);
  return $config;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "with fixer"?

Comment: I honestly don't remember what I meant with that. Perhaps I meant using Composer or some sort of CLI. EDIT: I believe using the global `php-cs-fixer` if it works or not, if so, then it's installed globally. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the `php-cs-fixer` like suggested in the [official github repo](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/doc/installation.rst), it's likely that you have installed the current version. At the moment it's V3 (V3.14.3 to be exact).

You can check your `php-cs-fixer` version by executing

```
php-cs-fixer -V
```

Unfortunately, the package `atom-beautify` (current version V0.33.4) seems to support `php-cs-fixer` up to version V2, like you can see in the package settings:
[image]

By using a newer version of the `php-cs-fixer`, `atom-beautify` seems to have probelms in finding your local custom config file (i.e. `.php-cs-fixer.php`, also `.php_cs` or `.php-cs.dist`), unless you specify the full path to it in the package settings, which only makes sense, if you are using the same custom configuration all over your projects.

**Long story short:** you can check whether your `php-cs-fixer` is working on its own and is loading your local custom configuration file by creating a test php file and executing

```
php-cs-fixer fix test.php
```

After that you have three options:

- Use `php-cs-fixer` in the command line
- Downgrade your `php-cs-fixer` to V2 and use the `atom-beautify` package
- Or use a current version of the `php-cs-fixer`, but use an other atom package instead. I ended up using the package [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/pfefferle/atom-php-cs-fixer) by pfefferle